# Swift - getting data out of a completion handler - decoding data

Tags: json, swift, urlsession

I am doing an api call to a zip code info site, and wrote a function to get the data, then parse it with the JSONDecoder...problem is, when I call that function, the data is trapped in the completion handler. Without having to use a delegate, is there a way to pull the values out of the completion handler to use elsewhere in my class?

```
struct ZipCodeDataManager {
    func getZipData(zipCode: String, userCompletionHandler: @escaping (ZipCodeCityData?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let urlString = "https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/apiKeyHere/info.json/\(zipCode)/degrees"
        
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                    do {
                        let parsedJSON = try jsonDecoder.decode(ZipCodeCityData.self, from: data)
                        let city = parsedJSON.city
                        let state = parsedJSON.state
                        let lat = parsedJSON.lat
                        let lng = parsedJSON.lng
                        
                        let finalData = ZipCodeCityData(city: city, state: state, lat: lat, lng: lng)
                        
                        userCompletionHandler(finalData, nil)
                        
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                        userCompletionHandler(nil,error)
                    }
                }
            })
            .resume()
        }
    }
}

struct ZipCodeCityData: Decodable {
    let city: String
    let state: String
    let lat: Double
    let lng: Double
}

let zipCodeManager = ZipCodeDataManager()


//these values aren't updating when the function is called
var city = ""
var state = ""
var lat = 0.0
var lng = 0.0

func getDataFromZip() {
    let zip = zipCodeManager.getZipData(zipCode: "91203") { (data, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }

        // trying to update the values here
        city = data!.city
        state = data!.state
        lat = data!.lat
        lng = data!.lng
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting the values in `parsedJSON` object ? debug or print it

Comment: yeah, when i run this in a playground I get values for each in the getZipData method

Comment: How can you tell that the values weren't updated? Where are you calling `getDataFromZip` from? And where are you checking?

Comment: You're using the result of the completion in `getDataFromZip()` so I'm not sure why you say that "the data is trapped in the completion handler".

Comment: Where do you call `getDataFromZip()`? And be aware that your code crashes reliably if an error occurs. Add an `else` clause in the completion handler or a return statement after `print(error)`. By the way: Print also the potential `URLSession` error.

Comment: Look at the code under the struct...I'm putting that code inside another class...however, if i try to set any properties with the info from the completion handler, they do not update...so like I said, its like the data is stuck inside the method and I can't get it out (despite xcode saying the vars are linked)

Comment: The *code under the struct* declares the method `getDataFromZip()` but it's not being called.

Comment: Well damn, you're right...I called the method and then printed the info, and it all worked...what a moron moment, thank you for your help (they might as well delete this question)...

Answer (score 1):

May try using public variables instead of the completion handler. I also used this method in one of my projects:

```
    //Posts image data in Constants class
func downloadImageFrom(urlString: String){
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    
    var data: Data?
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (d, r, e) in
        guard let dat = d else {
            print("No Data")
            return
        }
                
        guard r == r else {
            print("No Response")
            return
        }
                
        if let err = e {
            print("ERROR: \(err)")
        }
                
        data = dat
        Constants.imageData = data
            
            
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "NewImageData"), object: self)
            
            
    }.resume()
```